# определение объекта, используя ссылку C++

Tags: c++, ооп, память, ссылки, выделение-памяти

При чтении Лафоре "Объектно ориентированное программирование" увидел код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Dist{
private:
    int feet;
    int inches;
public:
    void setDist(){
        cout << "дюймы";cin >> inches;
        cout << "футы";cin >> feet;
    }
    void getDist(){
        cout << feet << "-" << inches;
    }
};

int main(){
    Dist& dst = *(new Dist); // не понятно - зачем мы здесь ставим &
    dst.setDist();
    dst.getDist();
    return 0;
}
```

зачем в данном случае используется &, если код будет работать и без него

Comment: Так нет лишнего копирования..

Comment: понял, но где конкретно происходит копирование Dist dst = *(new Dist); ? можете, пожалуйста, пояснить поподробнее

Comment: Создается объект в памяти, затем он используется для инициализации с помощью копирующего конструктора. Да, еще —  в примере со ссылкой (&) деструктор точно вызываться не будет :)

Comment: Сначала `new Dist` создает один объект с динамическим временем хранения, вызывая сгенерированный компилятором конструктор по-умолчанию. Затем `Dist dst = *(...)`  создает второй объект с автоматическим временем хранения, вызывая сгенерированный компилятором конструктор копирования, передавая туда ссылку на первый объект. При этом тут еще в любом случае происходит утечка памяти, ведь для объекта, созданного посредством `new`, не вызывается `delete`. Можно было бы написать просто `Dist dst{};`, было бы короче и корректнее.

Comment: Не очень ясно какое практическое применение данного примера. В случае с конкретным классом Dist лучше просто присовить и не устраивать танцы с бубном, ибо копироваться будут только 2 int-a, если у нас есть какая-то динамически выделенная память со сслыками на неё, то лучше использовать move constructor или move assignment operator. Единственное (по крайней мере, что мне приходит в голову) где конструкция как в примере может быть применена, так это если есть какой-то массив в классе, например, `int arr[5000]`, его и копировать будет тяготно и move semantics к нему не примененешь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильнее всего было бы просто `Dist dst;`, от `new` здесь никакой пользы.

> зачем в данном случае используется &, если код будет работать и без него

(1) `Dist &dst = *(new Dist);` и (2) `Dist dst = *(new Dist);` - это разные вещи. (1) - это просто бесполезное использование `new`. (2) тоже, но во втором случае вы еще и копируете получившийся объект, и теряете адрес оригинального объекта, поэтому не сможете позвать на нем `delete` и получаете гарантированную утечку памяти (а в первом случае можно сделать `delete &dst;`, чтобы освободить память).